# Inverse function theorem for DC-functions

Tags: real-analysis, tag-removed, reference-request

I would like to have an inverse (or/and) implicite function theorem for DC-functions.
It seems that I have right definitions, but I fail to prove it...

**Definitions:**

- Let $h:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a convex function and $x\in\mathbb R^n$, the set of all linear functionals $\ell:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that 
  $$h(y)\ge h(x)+\ell(y-x)$$
  is called **subdifferential** of $h$ at $x$ --- it will be denoted as $\partial_{x}h$. (In general $\partial_{x}h$ is a nonempty bounded convex set)
- $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is called **DC-function** if it is a difference between two convex functions.
- $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^k$ is called **DC-map** each coordinate function of $F$ is DC.
- $x\in\mathbb R^n$ is called **regular value of a DC-function** $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ if of $f=h_1-h_2$ for some convex functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ and $\partial_x h_1 + (-\partial_x h_2)\not\ni0$. Here $+$ denotes *Minkowski sum* and $(-\partial_x h_2)$ is reflection of $\partial_x h_2$ in the origin.
- $x\in\mathbb R^n$ is called **regular value of a DC-map** $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^k$ if $x$ is a regular value of $\ell\circ F$ for any non-zero linear map $\ell:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2911) an implicit function theorem for delta-convex functions is given in Theorem 4.4 of L. Veselý and L. Zajíček, "Delta-convex mappings between Banach spaces and applications." *Dissertationes Math. (Rozprawy Mat.)* **289** (1989).

Comment: FYI, if you can't get a copy of this easily, Zajíček's web page is http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~zajicek/

Comment: This theorem only says that implicit function is DC if it exists...
Just in case, here is a link to the paper:
http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/scans/DC.pdf